# How to attach sound effects to an AudioBuffer

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to add the following sound effects to some audio files, then grab their audio buffers and convert to .mp3 format

- Fade-out the first track
- Fade in the following tracks

  - A background track (and make it background by giving it a small gain node)
  - Another track that will serve as the more audible of both merged tracks
- Fade out the previous one and fade in the first track again

I observed the effects that are returned by the AudioParam class as well as those from the GainNode interface are attached to the context's destination instead of to the buffer itself. Is there a technique to espouse the AudioParam instance values (or the gain property) to the buffers so when I merge them into one ultimate buffer, they can still retain those effects? Or do those effects only have meaning to the destination (meaning I must `connect` on the sourceNode) and output them via OfflineContexts/startRendering? I tried this method previously and was told on my immediate last thread that I only needed one BaseAudioContext and it didn't have to be an OfflineContext. I think to have various effects on various files, I need several contexts, thus I'm stuck in the dilemma of various AudioParams and GainNodes but directly implicitly invoking them by calling start will inadvertently lose their potency.

The following snippets demonstrate the effects I'm referring to, while the full code can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/ka830Lqq/3/

```
var beginNodeGain = overallContext.createGain(); // Create a gain node


        beginNodeGain.gain.setValueAtTime(1.0, buffer.duration - 3); // make the volume high 3 secs before the end

        beginNodeGain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.01, buffer.duration); // reduce the volume to the minimum for the duration of expRampTime - setValTime i.e 3

        // connect the AudioBufferSourceNode to the gainNode and the gainNode to the destination
        begin.connect(beginNodeGain);
```

Another snippet goes thus

```
function handleBg (bgBuff) {

            var bgContext = new OfflineAudioContext(bgBuff.numberOfChannels, finalBuff[0].length, bgBuff.sampleRate), // using a new context here so we can utilize its individual gains

            bgAudBuff = bgContext.createBuffer(bgBuff.numberOfChannels, finalBuff[0].length, bgBuff.sampleRate),

            bgGainNode = bgContext.createGain(),

            smoothTrans =  new Float32Array(3);


            smoothTrans[0] = overallContext.currentTime; // should be 0, to usher it in but is actually between 5 and 6

            smoothTrans[1] = 1.0;

            smoothTrans[2] = 0.4; // make it flow in the background

            bgGainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0, 0); //currentTime here is 6.something-something

            bgGainNode.gain.setValueCurveAtTime(smoothTrans, 0, finalBuff.pop().duration); // start at `param 2` and last for `param 3` seconds. bgBuff.duration



            for (var channel = 0; channel < bgBuff.numberOfChannels; channel++) {

                 for (var j = 0; j < finalBuff[0].length; j++) {

                    var data = bgBuff.getChannelData(channel),

                    loopBuff = bgAudBuff.getChannelData(channel),

                    oldBuff = data[j] != void(0) ? data[j] : data[j - data.length];

                    loopBuff[j] = oldBuff;
                }
            }

            // instead of piping them to the output speakers, merge them

            mixArr.push(bgAudBuff);

            gottenBgBuff.then(handleBody());
        }
```

Comment: A fiddle that actually works would be really great to see what's going on.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work from that fiddle. While developing, I didn't use those files in the `constituents` array, rather I used files residing on my localhost. Please, if you don't mind, you can pull the code from that fiddle onto you local system and run it with your local files. Many thanks @RaymondToy

Comment: It doesn't work because the fiddle doesn't have access to the files (because of CORS restrictions).

Comment: Ok. That was one of the reasons why I was using localhost. Please feel free to host them where you have access to all the files

Comment: I won't have the same files as you, so I may or may not be able to reproduce the issue. (Because I haven't looked closely at the code yet.)

Comment: You mustn't have the same files as me sir. You can simply use any file of your choosing, then set the path in that constituents array. As long as the described effect is achieved. I myself don't even have the actual files that'll be used in the application yet, I just used dummy files on my computer